# How to link between a String that matches an Enum to the Enum itself in Java (to make IDE track its usage)

Tags: java, enums, jackson, annotations

One of the benefits of using IDE is it tracks your usage of different parts of the code, such as your usage of enums:

[image: enum usage example]

In Jackson (Java library) occasionally you are required to use strings in its custom annotations, if the string is actually a representation of a defined Enum, you lose this awesome tracking feature.

for example (the field `name` requires Strings that in this match the Enum values):

```java
public enum MyEnum {
    ENUM1,
    ENUM2
}

@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyClass1.class, name = "ENUM1"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyClass2.class, name = "ENUM2")
})
```

Unfortunately, I can't use the actual enum because it requires the value at compile time, so `.toString()` and `.name()` can't be used here.

And due to that, the IDE won't recognize it's being used.

##### The question is:

Is there a way I can preserve tracking when using Jackson annotations?
(maybe there's a hack to use the enum itself, or alternatively to mark that the used string is related to the enum? or anything else...)

Comment: You can always add a `JavaDoc` - `@see`, `@link` tags. You can mention about an enum in `JavaDoc` and `IDE` will find that usage. [Javadoc: @see and @link](https://www.baeldung.com/javadoc-see-vs-link)

Answer (score 0):

The value for annotation needs to be a compile time constant, so I think there is no straight forward way unless you use your own implementation of Annotation which might look like:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface TestAnnotation {
    MyEnum name() default MyEnum.Enum1;
}

enum MyEnum { 
    Enum1, 
    Enum2; 
}
```

@JsonSubTypes.Type's name uses String for which compile time constants can only be [primitive or String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

Comment: that's what I was afraid of, is there a way to manually flag the IDE that a given string is actually the usage of an ENUM property? I mean, I don't really care if it remains a string, I just want that when I 'rename' or 'safe delete' the IDE will know to address this usage as well

Comment: you might use simple logger to just print ENUM1  & ENUM2, inside a method where you are using JsonTypes annotation. This way, IDE knows this method too uses enum. Though this is not standard way but is a tactical workaround.

Comment: thought of that, kind of a messy workaround. thanks for the help!